# Position app-drawer underneath app-header

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using the template from starter kit 2, is it possible to have the app drawer below the `app-header`? Right now the app drawer starts from the top of viewport and is columnized next to `app-header`.

I would like my app to be like google keep and google cloud console where the app header spans the entire width of the viewport and the app drawer begins underneath.

After reading the element catalog for `app-layout`, I did not see a offical api/attribute to set this. I've tried a few things but no success:

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
  <!-- Drawer content -->
    <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

  <app-drawer>
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
      <a name="view2" href="/view2">View Two</a>
      <a name="view3" href="/view3">View Three</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you need to use an `app-drawer-layout` inside an `app-header-layout`.

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/baqumi/edit?html,output) with the desired layout.

And the code itself:

```
<dom-module id="test-app">
  <template>

    <style>

      :host {
        display: block;
        --app-primary-color: #3F51B5;
      }

      app-header {
        background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
        color: white;
      }

      app-drawer {
        top: 64px;
        --app-drawer-content-container: {
          padding: 0px;
          background-color: #eee;
        };
      }

    </style>

    <app-header-layout fullbleed>
      <app-header fixed shadow>
        <app-toolbar id="toolbar">
          <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="_onTap"></paper-icon-button>
          <div main-title>Stormwind</div>
        </app-toolbar>
      </app-header>
      <app-drawer-layout>
        <app-drawer id="drawer">
          drawer content
        </app-drawer>
        <div>
          main content
        </div>
      </app-drawer-layout>
    </app-header-layout>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'test-app',

      properties: {

      },

      ready: function() {

      },

      attached: function() {

      },

      _onTap: function() {
        this.$.drawer.toggle();
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**NOTE**

You need to manually handle the drawer button (the `drawer-toggle` property won't work).

Comment: So cool, thanks! For some reason I thought `app-drawer-layout` always had to be the parent container for everything.

Comment: Nice. Yeah I prefer this layout too. What does this mean if you want to use some of the larger header effects which condense on scroll like <app-header condenses style=“200px;”></app-header> ? The app-drawer would have to move up/down somehow like Google Inbox I presume?

Comment: @Rhys You are right, using those `app-header` effects would require to modify the drawer also. I can imagine moving the drawer with some sort of animation based on the app-header position and state. Check the `app-header` documentation (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-header), there is a `thresholdTriggered` boolean property and also a `getScrollState()` function to use for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @Rhys You don't need such a heavy handed solution, just add position static on the app-drawer so it isn't position fixed and it'll move up as the header collapses